# Geoserver creates slow PSQL queries

Tags: gis, psql, geoserver

I'm experiencing some slowness with Geoserver + PostGIS. Filtering a layer takes huge amounts of time for Geoserver to render the tiles.

For instance I have an array of IDs that need to be shown so I make a CQL_FILTER like

```
CQL_FILTER="id IN ('1', '2')"
```

I have checked the query logger in PSQL and the query looks like

```
SELECT "objectid",encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force2D("the_geom")),'base64') as "the_geom" FROM "public"."table" WHERE ((("id" = '1' AND "id" IS NOT NULL ) OR ("id" = '2' AND "id" IS NOT NULL )
```

Of course I need to query hundreds of IDs and the PSQL query takes about 30 seconds to finish. But if I just do this query:

```
SELECT "objectid",encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force2D("the_geom")),'base64') as "the_geom" FROM "public"."table" WHERE id IN ('1', '2')
```

the query finishes in ~1s. Is there any way to "optimize" the way GeoServer writes the queries?

I have tried optimizing the PSQL server by increasing cache sizes, optimizing for M2 SSD and prewarming

Thanks!

Edit:

Removing rows with where the ID is null, adding a `NOT NULL` statement to the column inside PSQL and reloading the layer inside GeoServer removed the `"id" IS NOT NULL` from the query and the query time is half what it used to be, but it's still not good enough. It really should be just a simple `IN` query.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading PSQL to 10.2 fixed the issue, the index is still not used on the OR query but it's 10 times faster.